# Has anyone performed joins using 3 tables in cascading

Tags: hadoop, cascading

Cascading is one of the best framework to deal with hadood jobs by  using simple data flows.

Has anyone tried and performed joins usings 3 tables in cascading, if so can u please share ur ideas regarding joins in cascading and **how to perform join on 3 tables?.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cascading supports mutliple joins we can do this by using

```
CoGroup(pipes[],fieldnames[],DeclaredFields[],mixedjoin(boolean[]));
```

**boolean** is a set of arrays which indicate the whether the is innerjoin(true) or outerjoin(false).